# wc_print_notices is not displaying any messages in woocommerce pages?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used default woocommerce templates for shop, cart and single page.
I have not removed any hooks either but also I am not getting any message.
Any Idea?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product',   'Cusotm_wc_print_notices', 10 );
function Cusotm_wc_print_notices()
{
   echo 'Hook is working fine';
}
```

I am getting this message 'Hook is working fine' but not wc_print_notices();.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is the problem. Your question needs further details. With that said, can you try adding this code to your functions.php of your current theme.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'test' );
function test() {

    wc_add_notice( __( 'Sorry there was a problem.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );

}
```

Let me know if it does something.

---

**UPDATE**

If you have something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product',   'Cusotm_wc_print_notices', 10 );
function Cusotm_wc_print_notices()
{
   $notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices');
   print_r($notices);
}
```

it will not work because `$notices` will be empty once `wc_print_notices()` is called.

try changing priority and you will get something. Should be something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product',   'Cusotm_wc_print_notices', 9 );
```

[image: reigelgallarde.me]
use priority below 10. Because WooCommerce is using 10.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
```

Comment: The above code is displaying the error message of "Sorry there was a problem." and is working fine but I am unable to display wc_print_notices().

Comment: actually,  $notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices', array()); is not displaying any thing, When I do var_dump($notices), it displays => array(0) { }.

Comment: when `wc_print_notices` is called once, your `$notices` will not get anything because everything will be cleared.

Comment: you can get it before it is called.

Comment: example, try doing `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product',   'Cusotm_wc_print_notices', 9 );` and do `$notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices');` inside `function Cusotm_wc_print_notices(){}`. NOTE that i'm using 9 as priority.

Comment: I have added following code on function.php so get output in single product and cart page but I am getting NULL.
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'Cusotm_wc_print_notices', 9 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'Cusotm_wc_print_notices', 9 );
function Cusotm_wc_print_notices()
{
 $notices = WC()->session->get('wc_notices');
 var_dump($notices);
}
output => NULL

Comment: I can't further assist you. As you can see in my screenshot it has value...

Comment: have you added the test function too?

Comment: The above code is working fine for me as well. when I do var_dump, I am getting this output which is fine. array(1) { ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(26) "Sorry there was a problem." } }

Comment: But when I try to display or output the wc_notices, I am not getting any output even if I add something to cart.